# Permission denied to access files at URL, but the permissions are set to allow access

Tags: permissions

I have these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  10 paam paam  4096 Sep  5 18:25 extra_drive
```

The same permission is given to subfolders and to the files in folders.

In my `*.conf` file I have

```
Alias "/user_files" "/extra_drive"
```

Yet, when trying to go to a certain file from a url

```
https://foo.org/user_files/9/20/blah.docx
```

I get:

```
You don't have permission to access /user_files/9/20/blah.docx
```

Comment: "from a url" so the user and group you do this with is not "paam". If apache: it should be www-data or apache if you kept the default user.

Comment: I have the same thing working on a different server. I just can't figure out where is the difference. Is there another place where we define permissions?

Comment: It seems like this question is lacking detail - you could give some information on the environment, at a minimum, `.conf` file of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

In this file:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I had to add this:

```
<Directory /extra_drive>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```